# How to combine Boost.Spirit customization points with Nabialek?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

First things first: I'm using the default C++ language standard for MS Visual Studio 2017 (v15.19.11), C++14, along with Boost v1.65.1

I have an input file formatted like this:

```
IterName        SomeName
IterDesc        Some Description
COLUMNS fname.XCT               posn.detect.R           posn.source.z
        expt_KF000000.raw       0.0                     27.639320225002102
        expt_KF000180.raw       216.34457142857138      30.584848796430673
        expt_KF000360.raw       72.68914285714277       33.530377367859245
```

I am trying to parse & load this into a structure like the following:

```cpp
struct Stax { std::string stage, axis; };
struct Configuration {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> filenames; // "expt_KF000000.raw": "XCT", "other_file.raw": "OCT"
    std::map<double, Stax> positions;  // 0.0: ["Detect", "R"], 27.639: ["Source", "Z"]
};
struct Iteration {
    std::string name;
    std::string descript;
    std::vector<Configuration> configs;
};
```

Each line after the one containing "**COLUMNS**" should generate a new `Configuration` instance to be added to `Iteration.configs`.

As implied by the comments in the code, some columns may be missing ("**fname.OCT**" in this example)... but the order of the columns may vary (as will the number) so I've tried using local rule state to hold a variable number of parsers, one for each column, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31382602/1206102

The elements of `Configuration.positions` are composed of info following the "**posn.**" header string plus any content parsed from the cell itself.  Likewise, elements of `Configuration.filenames` are composed of whatever follows "**fname.**" in the header plus the cell content.  So I have to somehow save the info I parse from the header row in order to use later when the cells are parsed... so I store this alongside the cell parsers in the rule local state var.

I've tried all manner of things from rule locals to Phoenix-wrapped data members, from direct attribute propagation to Fusion-adapted structs & "customization points", even `attr_cast`'s with `transform_attribute` specializations... but nothing has successfully compiled yet.  My list of attempts follows:

1. https://wandbox.org/permlink/fU1WOazzxOVPbh9n
2. https://wandbox.org/permlink/Itlq3HfydUByUSaH
3. https://wandbox.org/permlink/96yDzVpCpI0K4ujs
4. https://wandbox.org/permlink/u8iWv61jJSQv01bU

My last attempt still produces 11 compile-time errors, the 1st of which (`'const_iterator': is not a member of 'Configuration'`) is telling: something (Qi/Fusion/Phoenix) is expecting `Configuration` to be iterable... probably because the parsed type that populates it is (a vector of tuples).

That may be the crux of my problem: I'm trying to stuff a parsed iterable into a non-iterable* complex struct: some of the tuples in the parsed vector will go into one data member of the struct, while others will go into a different data member.  (*I say non-iterable because it makes no sense to iterate on `Configuration` but if Qi/Fusion/Phoenix insists I could try to accomodate.  In fact you'll see a [commented out] attempt to define the `const_iterator` type for `Configuration`.)

I want to accomplish this using Boost.Spirit if at all possible so... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. `&cell_stage` does not take an address of `cell_stage` because `operator&` is overloaded. Use `boost/std::addressof` to obtain the address.
2. `qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, double()>*` cannot be converted to `qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, boost::variant<std::string, double, bool>>*`
3. In `qi::eps[_offset = -1, px::ref(_ncols) = px::size(_tstore)]` you just assign `-1` to `_offset` at initialization, it has to be `px::ref(_offset) = -1`
4. The `qi::repeat(_ncols)` will repeat not `_ncols` times, but the number that `_ncols` contained at the rule creation time, which is zero.
5. In `qi::eps[_offset = ++_offset % _ncols]`, like the in previous ones, you do not create a Phoenix lambda, but just something like `qi::eps[0]`. It has to be `qi::eps[px::ref(_offset) = ++px::ref(_offset) % px::cref(_ncols)]`.
6. I did not dig what `qi::attr(_tstore[_offset]) >> *_pstore[_offset]` should be doing, but it is clearly not what you actually meant, probably `qi::lazy(px::cref(_tstore)[_offset]) >> qi::lazy(px::cref(_pstore)[_offset])`.

At this point I has to stop and ask: Do you really want to make this working?

Do not use Spirit as a [Birmingham screwdriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). You are not forced to make all the things in a single Spirit parser. For example, you can parse rows in a usual for-loop and it will be much simpler to write and maintain.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, but #1 and #4 don't cause problems in one of my earlier working examples (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2116fc892b9ecaf2) but maybe I broke them by using data members instead of locals.  And point taken about the best tool for the job, but I've seen Spirit successfully hammer some pretty complicated nails.

Comment: Trivia: I think `qi::repeat(px::ref(_ncols))` is supported and does what OP seemingly expected